# jQuery get and Load not working, but running

Tags: php, jquery

**Hello Stackers**

I'm back again, yet with another jQuery question. I've been trying to let a span in a button with the ID #notificationbutton refresh every x seconds, however, the code runs, the console doesn't show even a error, but it just doesn't load in the other page.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("notifyer.php", function (result) {
            $('#notificationbutton').html(result);
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

**The Button with SPAN**

```
<button id="open_notificationcenter" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" target="_new"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" style="padding-right:5px; padding-top:1px;" aria-hidden="true"></span><span id="notifcationbutton"><?php echo $notif_count; ?></span></button>
```

**The file notifyer.php**

```
<?php
echo $notif_count; 
?>
```

When I Surf to the notifyer.php file, it does show the actual count. The problem is the jQuery, it just doesn't update it! What am I not getting here?

Comment: have you tried to console.log your result to see what the server sends to the client?

Comment: @errand Yes, I tried `console.log(result);` and it returned the wanted result.

Comment: ok ... try to change <span id="notifcationbutton"> to <span id="notificationbutton"> to match your selector from the js part ;) just a typo, it seems...